# How to sort a multidimensional object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, multidimensional-array

How to sort the objects by age value?

I have the following object structure

```
{
    "men": {
        "20114": {
            "id": "20114",
            "name": "Peter",
            "age": "21"
        },
        "28957": {
            "id": "28957",
            "name": "Paul",
            "age": "20"
        }
    },
    "women": {
        "8957": {
            "id": "8957",
            "name": "Rose",
            "age": "24"
        },
        "2178": {
            "id": "2178",
            "name": "Sara",
            "age": "22"
        }
    },
}
```

I know, that I can sort arrays like this

```
groups.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.age - a.age;
});
```

but how to do this with objects?

Comment: You can´t, objects keys do not have a defined order. You either have to pass the objects to array, or make a new array with keys and sort that, based on the object data

Comment: As @juvian said, objects don't have a defined order to them. So you will want to change `"men"` and `"women"` into an array of objects, and then sort with your method above.

Comment: I agree with @juvian. You could have a `gender` property instead and create an array of people.

Comment: @Aley What is expected result ?

Comment: It's an object, because I need the ID as an index. So I can do `delete groups['men']['20114']`. @guest271314 I want the object be sorted by the age property.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot easier to sort your data if you could change your structure to the JSON model below:

```js
var data = [
    {
        "id": "20114",
        "name": "Peter",
        "age": "21",
        "gender": "men"
    },
    {
        "id": "28957",
        "name": "Paul",
        "age": "20",
        "gender": "men"
    },
    {
        "id": "8957",
        "name": "Rose",
        "age": "24",
        "gender": "women"
    },
    {
        "id": "2178",
        "name": "Sara",
        "age": "22",
        "gender": "women"
    }
]

data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.age) - parseFloat(b.age);
});

data.sort()


document.write(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortfunc(prop){
                 return function(obj1,obj2){
                var val1 = obj1[prop];
                 var val2 = obj2[prop];

            return val1 - val2;

      };
}

groups.sort(sortfunc(prop));
```

pass `prop` as property name

Comment: Please read the question, again, the OP knows how to sort arrays. They have this method already in their answer.